# Side by Side Responsive Images w/o Reflow

Tags: html, css, reflow

Wanting to display 2 responsive images without having the browser reflow the screen as the images are loaded. I am currently using a modified version from this answer: [responsive-design, image, how to set width/height to avoid reflow on image-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850988/responsive-design-image-how-to-set-width-height-to-avoid-reflow-on-image-load)

Here is the fiddle for a single responsive image: https://jsfiddle.net/hxraak4u/

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper" style="max-width: 608px; ">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 49.34%; "> <!-- Height / Width -->
        <img src="http://met.live.mediaspanonline.com/assets/31069/example-608web_w608.jpg" style="max-height: 300px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper {
    margin: 15px auto;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.image-wrapper div {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-wrapper div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Note: I'm using some inline styles are because I am using Razor to create the HTML for the image and to set the width, height, and height/width (bottom padding %).

I am now trying to get 2 different height images to display side by side while preserving what I already have working. Specifically:

- different height images to display side by side
- images are centered in their parent div
- images are not displayed larger than 100%
- have these 2 images stack vertically if the width of the display decreases to be less than the width of either of the 2 images
- if the display shrinks further, shrink the width of the images as necessary while preserving the width:height ratio - standard responsive UI
- when printing, don't break images over pages, whether it be 2 images on a row or one, but don't require both images together to not break over a page when they are on different rows
- when the HTML is loaded, reserve vertical space for each image based on the width of the display and the width/height ratio - prevent reflow

Comment: Update: For the 4th bullet above "have these 2 images stack vertically if the width of the display decreases to be less than the width of either of the 2 images", meant to say "if width decreases to be less than width of both images together"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DEMO: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v8ovqrvm/)

### Alt: [Full Screen](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v8ovqrvm/embedded/result/)

### HTML/CSS

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
html { box-sizing: border-box; font: 700 16px/1.5 Consolas; }

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }

.flexWrapper { margin: 2em auto; max-width: 38em; page-break-inside: avoid; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; }

.flex { width: -moz-fit-content; width: -webkit-fit-content; width: fit-content; height: -moz-fit-content; height: -webkit-fit-content; height: fit-content; overflow: none; outline: 3px solid red; flex: 0 1 auto; }

.exampleImg0, .exampleImg1 { max-height: 20em; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }

@media screen and (max-width:37em) {
  .flexWrapper { flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="flexWrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <img class="exampleImg0" src="http://met.live.mediaspanonline.com/assets/31069/example-608web_w608.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img class="exampleImg1" src="http://placehold.it/240x320/fff/000.png&text=240x320" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Fundamental** changes were made, such as:

- [`box-sizing`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
- [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485720/which-html5-reset-css-do-you-use-and-why) of `margin`, `padding`, and `border`
- `font-size`is declared at [`root`](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/)

  just for evening out how everything behaves for measuring purposes, positioning, etc...

**Renamed** the elements (I need to use weird names to associate things better)

- `.image-wrapper`.............. `.flexWrapper`
- ``` .image-wrapper``div ```......... `.flex`
- ``` .image-wrapper``div ``` `img`... `.exampleImg0` (original img) 
                                     and 
                                `.exampleImg1` (added img)

**Brief Explanation:**

- ``` .flexWrapper``{ display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;... ``` See [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) `
- `.flex` `{ width: -moz-fit-content; width: -webkit-fit-content; width: fit-content; height: -moz-fit-content; height: -webkit-fit-content; height: fit-content; overflow: none;`... See [this](http://demosthenes.info/blog/975/Little-Big-Using-CSS-fit-content)
                               ...`outline: 3px solid red;` just to see the flex-items better... 
                   ...`flex: 0 1 auto; }` This allows the 2 divs (.flex) that wrap the imgs to behave pretty much within the criteria you established.
- `.exampleImg0, .exampleImg1` `{ max-height: 20em; width: 100%;
  height: 100%; display: block; }` These properties help the imgs
  center within it's parent, `.flex` and maintain a responsive ratio.
- a simple media query...`@media screen and (max-width:37em) {
       .flexWrapper { flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
     }` ... so whenever the images shrink, they'll stack on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this tonight.

Comment: OK. Wasn't aware of the flex logic. Think I got it working with the different height images, and avoided the media query by using flex-wrap: wrap. https://jsfiddle.net/hxraak4u/4/