# Defining responsive images in a way that doesn't cause browser reflow over slow connections (HTML preferred)

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a web app of mine, I want images served to the user to be responsive. Moreover, I'd also want to specify `width` and `height` attributes in the image tag, so that over slow mobile connection, there's no browser reflow.

Are **both** of these requirements achievable via using pure HTML?

If it's indeed possible, an illustrative answer that shows working examples is most welcome. Secondary pure JS (no libraries) answers are welcome too (but my primary focus is doing this via lightweight HTML).

Note: this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645618/4936905) from a similar question relies on JQuery (something I'm not versed in), hence doesn't meet my requirement.

---

**Background:** for mobile-responsive design it's common to specify a width (or max-width), and define height as `auto`. That would clash with (and be antithetical to) `width` and `height` values. Hence my question.

Comment: (The answer from that other question could easily be re-written to vanilla JS ...)

Comment: @CBroe: I don't know JQuery, so I'm unable to translate that to vanilla JS. I'm primarily a server-side developer with rudimentary HTML, JS knowledge.

Comment: @CBroe: Yea I don't want to do this in JS either. I've tried something like `<img src="image.png" style="max-width:400px;width:100%">` to make the image responsive. Now if I tack on `width` and `height` attributes, I lose my responsiveness (but solve the problem of browser reflows). I want to enable *both* requirements, preferably in pure HTML. Are you suggesting I should try `width:auto`? Would be good to get an illustrative example.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/133-figuring-responsive-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a vanilla version of [that jQuery answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645618/4936905).

```js
// convert nodelist into array:
var imageList = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementsByTagName('img')
);

imageList.forEach(function(img) {
  // only act on images with set w+h attributes:
  if (img.getAttribute("width") && img.getAttribute("height")) {
    // calculate the desired height (in pixels)
    var scaledHeight = img.getAttribute("height") * img.clientWidth / img.getAttribute("width");

    // wrap the image in an element with that height
    var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    wrapper.setAttribute("style", "height: " + scaledHeight + "px; display: inline-block");
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, img);
    wrapper.appendChild(img);
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Just so you can see what it's doing: */
span {border:1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/2500x100" width="2500" height="100">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" width="1000" height="300">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```

And for even more completeness, a jQuery version of the above, which unlike the original answer works correctly.  (The older answer may depend on CSS not shown, or something else has changed since it was written, or it's just wrong; in any case it adds way too much padding.)

```js
$('img').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).attr("width") && $(this).attr("height")) {
      var scaledHeight = $(this).attr("height") * $(this).width() / $(this).attr("width");
      $(this).wrap('<span style="height: '+scaledHeight+'px; display:inline-block">');
    }
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Just so you can see what it's doing: */
span {border:1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/2500x100" width="2500" height="100">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" width="1000" height="300">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take it for a spin. I was hoping a pure HTML solution would be possible - I was thinking something maybe utilising `flex`. But fair enough.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if there is a non-js approach, I'll be watching this question with interest to see if someone more knowledgeable than me comes along...  It's a little mysterious to me that browsers don't do this automatically TBH.